# Button gets non-clickable when code for modal window is added

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button to launch a modal window

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-wide" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"  >Launch Modal </a>
```

When I add the following markup for modal window (copied from bootstrap's site itself), I can't click on the button. When it's removed, the button becomes clickable again.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly here http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/fkqu40ma/

Comment: The above code is perfectly correct.There may be some issues in other parts of the code that you have not shown

Comment: what the possible reasons might be? Could it be because of my css?

Comment: Ok, fixed. It was my css. thank you guys.